# How to add label above the scatter plot?

Tags: css, d3.js, rickshaw

I am developing a graph using [the rickshaw library](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/). Is there any option to create a label outside the scatter plot with the label above the bubble, [like in this example done with d3.js](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269)? [Here is my attempt at it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sspboyd/pe6xW/9/).

```
        .axis path,
        .axis line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: black;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }

        .axis text {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 11px;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You should look into the rickshaw.js file and try to append the text above the Scatter plot. It`s easy if you know the basic concept of d3.js.